# IntelliJ/PyCharm: Connection to localhost MySQL failed

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, pycharm, database-connection

I am using PyCharm to connect to my local MySQL database running at localhost port 3306. Here's my JDBC url in the "Data Sources and Drivers" window as shown by PyCharm:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

When I try to connect or click "Test Connection" I am getting this error in IntelliJ:

```
Error: Connection to MySQL failed.

Connection to Local MySQL failed.
[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I can connect to mysql using the command-line client just fine, it's just PyCharm that's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your MySQL isn't listening on IPv6 address. For some reason IntelliJ/PyCharm has problems when connecting to MySQL running on IPv6 address.

To see what address your MySQL server is listening on, type:

```
$ ss -ntl|grep 3306 
LISTEN      0      80       [::1]:3306                  [::]:*
```

The `[::1]:3306` part means it's listening on IPv6 address on localhost.

To change to IPv4, open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add/set the `bind-address` parameter in `[mysqld]` section to `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`:

```
...
[mysqld]
...
port = 3306
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
...
```

Then restart `mysqld.service` and you'll be able to connect via IntelliJ/PyCharm.